# Twitter search box widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I am making calls to twitter dynamically to get the widget on the web site. http://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_search

Instead of user getting the code from the above website, I am giving a text box to enter the same details to get the twitter search widget box.

I am able to get the tweets, but its removing the previous content and which is already on the page and updating the same page with only twitter feeds. 
Here is the code:

```
<label>Enter Search Keyword:</label>
<input type="text" id="twtKeyword"/>
<br/><br/>

<label>Enter Title:</label>
<input type="text" id="twtTitle"/>
<br/><br/>

<label>Enter Subject:</label>
<input type="text" id="twtSubject"/>
<br/><br/>

<input type="button" id="twtBtnClick" value="Click" onclick="getPageTwitter();"></input>









function getPageTwitter()
{
    var searchWord=document.getElementById("twtKeyword").value;
    var titleTwt=document.getElementById("twtTitle").value;
    var subjectTwt=document.getElementById("twtSubject").value;

    $( "#twitterWidget" ).dialog( "close" );


  new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'search',
  search: searchWord,
  interval: 6000,
  title: titleTwt,
  subject: subjectTwt,
  width: 250,
  height: 300,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#8ec1da',
      color: '#ffffff'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#ffffff',
      color: '#444444',
      links: '#1985b5'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: true,
    live: true,
    hashtags: true,
    timestamp: true,
    avatars: true,
    toptweets: true,
    behavior: 'default'
  }
}).render().start();


}
```

But I want the widget to stay in the same page without effecting the previous content of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't something the Search Widget was designed for. You will likely have to write your own JavaScript to poll the [Search API](https://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/search) and render the results with your own code.

Answer (score 1):

I think i've the answer for you. I got some coding done to do exactly what you want, Maybe you could iframe a page i'd be willing to setup? up to you.

you can view the page here [http://www.twitamix.com](http://twitamix.com)

Comment: thanks a lot its awesome I visited the site, but it has to be applied dynamically in my case. How do I do it. Please share some tips and u r thoughts. That would be great.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment :-) Can you explain more about applied dynamically? I'll help as much as i can